# Find the nodes in the percona cluster

Tags: python, percona

How do I find the number of nodes and node ip addresses in the Percona XtraDB cluster from inside a Python application? I know the IP address of one node in the cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by executing

> show variables like 'wsrep_cluster_address';

For example using sqlalchemy, you can do this by:

```
engine.execute("SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'wsrep_cluster_address'").fetchone()
```